# Let $f(t) = \frac{t - x}{t + y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the problem.

> Let $$f(t) = \frac{t - x}{t + y}.$$
>
> Show that $$f(x + y) + f(x - y) = \frac{-2y^2}{x^2 + 2xy}.$$

I know that this is just some substitution followed by simplification, but am missing the point of the let $f(t) = (t - x)/(t + y)$.  It doesn't seem to fit into the "show that" portion of the question.  Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: It just defines what $f$ means in the next line. $x$ and $y$ must be presumed to be constants that don't change during the entire problem (since they are free in the definition of $f$ and have not previously been assigned a meaning).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quantities $x$ and $y$ are some fixed quantities. Given any number $a$, 
$$f(a) = \frac{a-x}{a+y}.$$
Now, what happens if $a$ is equal to $x+y$? Will
$$f(x+y) = \frac{(x+y) - x}{(x+y) + y} = \frac{y}{x+2y}.$$

Similarly, what happens if $a$ is $x-y$?  You plug in $x-y$ for $t$ into the formula.

So, plug in $x+y$ for $t$; plug in $x-y$ for $t$. Add the results. See if you get what you are supposed to get.

Comment: Thank you, the problem appears so much clearer when elaborated in this fashion.

Comment: Arturo has that effect on lots of people!

Comment: Also, thanks to everyone for properly formatting my request, it was most appreciated!